# Configuring JSP with J2EE server in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, maven, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm having a specific configuration here. Trying to run JSP on J2EE preview server in a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. I'm aware through other answers that it can be made to work by changing to a Maven project, adding dependencies and/or by using a Tomcat server. But I want to know if there's anything to be re-configured to make it work with my configuration or is it simply that a J2EE preview server cannot handle .jsp ?

The error I get on console is:

> No JSP support. Check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp and that JSP option has been specified to start.jar

And the error on browser is: `

> HTTP ERROR 500 JSP support not configured

Answer (score 1):

The Preview server doesn't support JSPs. You will have to use a full Servlet container like Apache Tomcat.